# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: orders.events index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('608e6a80931b45001aa7f910') }

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

So actually I,m getting this error.
I have 2 models: one for event and the other for orders where i"m first storing the event instance in database from one routes and on other routes when i find it and refer it in order and try to save it then following error is coming

```sh
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: orders.events index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('608e6bde6ae9e80019f01dfe') }
[orders]     at Function.create (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/error.js:57:12)
[orders]     at toError (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123:22)
[orders]     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/common_functions.js:258:39
[orders]     at handler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:944:24)
[orders]     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:350:13
[orders]     at handleOperationResult (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
[orders]     at MessageStream.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:277:5)
[orders]     at MessageStream.emit (node:events:369:20)
[orders]     at processIncomingData (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
[orders]     at MessageStream._write (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
[orders]     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:395:12)
[orders]     at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:340:10)
[orders]     at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:750:22)
[orders]     at Socket.emit (node:events:369:20)
[orders]     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:313:12)
[orders]     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:288:9)
[orders] [ERROR] 09:09:09 MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: orders.events index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('608e6bde6ae9e80019f01dfe') }
```

My event and order schema are as follows:

event:

```
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    creatorId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }  
});
```

order:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    event: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Event'
    }   
});
```

And my code is as below:

```
const event = await Event.findById(eventId);

if (!event) {
        throw new NotFoundError();
    }

const order = Order.build({
        userId: req.currentUser!.id,
        event
})

order.save();
```

I already have stored event document in database which i can refer by just finding it.

Answer (score 0):

please try removing the database once and try adding new documents.
As you've referred to the event key from the order collection.